# How to determine the if a point is local maximum or minimum when function has vanishing second derivative?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $\cos x -\frac{1}{4}\cos2x$. At point $0$, the second and third derivative are both zero, but the forth derivative is negative. Is there a way to test if the function has local minimum or maximum at $0$?

Comment: There is a [higher order derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test). Basically, the idea is to reduce, using Taylor's theorem, to the case of the polynomials $x^n$. They contain all the information you need

Comment: You can also check the sign of the first derivative across the required point. In this case, the sign of the first derivative changes from negative to positive across the point $x=0$. Hence, there exists a local maxima at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Higher-derivative test**

| The function's lowest-order nonzero derivative is$\ldots$ | The stationary point is$\dots$ |
| --- | --- |
| of even order and positive | a local minimum point |
| of even order and negative | a local maximum point |
| of odd order at least $3^\text{rd}$ | an inflexion point |
| otherwise | <inconclusive> |

Thus, the given function has a local maximum point at $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Taylor polynomial about x=0 is
$$P(x) = f(0) + (f^{(4)} (0)/{4!})x^4+....= 3/4-(5/{24})x^4+...$$
Thus the point $x=0$ is a maximizer of the Taylor  polynomial and the same goes for the function.