# Why second derivative doesn't work for $x^4$ graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is clear from the graph of $x^4$ that it should have a positive second derivative at 0 like the graph of $x^2$ but instead because it has 0 the test fails. So what is the fundamental problem with the test because of which it fails for this graph.[image]

Comment: What "test" are you referring to?

Comment: $x^4$ curves up slower than any $ax^2,a>0$ at $x=0$, so comparing its behavior to a quadratic function (which is basically what the second derivative test does) tells you nothing.

Comment: The **second derivative test** here has not given you any false information, so it has not "failed" (and does not have a fundamental problem). $\quad$ The [**higher-derivative test**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4241684/21813) reveals that the point in question is a local minimum.

Comment: If $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)\gt 0$ then we have a local minimum. The converse is not necessarily true. In fact, $f(x)=|x|$ has a local minimum at $x=0$ and it is not even differentiable at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

If the function is concave up at some point $x_0$, then it means the first derivative function $f'(x)$ is increasing at the neighborhood of $x_0$. So what you can do is to compare the value for $f'(x_0-\epsilon)$ and $f'(x_0+\epsilon)$.

For this problem, $f'(x)=4x^3$ and $x_0=0$, so you can compare $f'(-\epsilon)$ and $f'(+\epsilon)$.

$$-4\epsilon^3=f'(-\epsilon)<f'(+\epsilon)=4\epsilon^3$$

Since the first derivative is increasing at the neighborhood of $0$, so it is concave up there.